# Where to advertise for a Blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, ads, blackberry-world

Android and iOS have several advertising platforms on the rise, Admob, Mobfox and others that i can use to advertise my app. But what are my options for a blackberry app, the mentioned networks does not seem to support Blackberry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BlackBerry advertising service: https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_services/advertising.html